# function to change argument to another sign

Tags: javascript, jquery

I dynamically create this list element and information a user has typed in shows up in it when a button is clicked 'info' is text and shuld show as it is but 'grade' is a number that i want to convert to another sign with the function changeNumber() but I am new to javascript and cant figure out how to make this function, can anyone give a suggestion or point me in the right direction?

```
    var list = $("#filmlista");
    var list_array = new Array();

    function updateFilmList()
{
        document.getElementById("name").value = '';
        document.getElementById("star").value = 0;
        var listan = list_array[0][0];
        var grade = list_array[0][1];
        var element = '<li class="lista">' + list + '<span class="grade">'+ changeNumber(grade) +'</span></li>';
        list.append(element);

}
```

should I use innerHTML? not shure I understand how it works? and how do I use the replace method if I have to replace many different numbers to the amount of signs the number is?

for example if the number is 5 it should show up as: `*****`, if number is 3 show up as: `***` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that should do the trick:

Add this function into your script.

```
function changeNumber(number) {
    var finalProduct = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        finalProduct += "*";
    }

    return finalProduct;
}
```

Replace the updateFilmsList with this code.

```
document.getElementById("name").value = '';
document.getElementById("star").value = 0;
var listan = list_array[0][0];
var grade = changeNumber(list_array[0][1]);
var element = '<li class="lista">' + list + '<span class="grade">'+ grade +'</span></li>';

list.append(element);
```

Comment: it says undefined where the stars should be?

Comment: In the fiddle? Showing *** for me in the alert.

Comment: how do I append it to the span element?

Comment: yes it seems to work, the alert shows me the right amount of stars to but I need it to append in the span element?

Comment: I updated the fiddle, enter a number in the input, click the button, it appends below: http://jsfiddle.net/27T5D/2/

Comment: For your code, change the append statement in mine to "return finalProduct;" and it should work.

Comment: the problem is that i cant use id because i create the element dynamically

Comment: Can you post more of your code then so I can see the whole picture (html)

Comment: i need to be able to add more than one list element and each time it should convert the number to x amount of stars so it shows up in a list

Comment: dont know how much code you need, before the code I updatet now there is code for the button to, the button clicked function takes the text field and the grade field and puts it into an array then pushes this array into the array i posted as list_array

Comment: now it says it cant read property '0' of undefined in the list_array?

Comment: seems to work but i need to have the value of the number still in the array, mayby thats why i tried to change it in the list element, because another function sorts the list by the number in the array? any idea of how to do the same thing but while calling the function from the list element?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do something like PHP's `str_repeat`. In that case, take a look at [`str_repeat` from PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/functions/str_repeat/)

Comment: i just want to convert the number to amount of stars the number is... in javascript and not php

Comment: That's why I gave you a link to PHPJS, which takes PHP functions and converts them to JavaScript for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are options other than a loop:

```
function charString(n, c) {
  n = n? ++n : 0;
  return new Array(n).join(c);
}

charString(3, '*'); // ***
```

You can use innerHTML to set the text content of an element provided none of the text might be mistaken for markup. Otherwise, set the textContent (W3C compliant) or innerText (IE proprietary but widely implemented) property as appropriate.